# Borrowed value does not live long enough when creating reference to parent node

Tags: rust, ownership

I'm trying to learn Rust, and for that I decided to implement Depth First Search algorithm.

So far I have the following Node struct:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Node<'a> {
    parent: Option<&'a Node<'a>>,
    position: crate::entities::Position,
}
```

As you can see every time I create a node there is a reference to its parent.

Now, I have the dfs algorithm:

```
pub fn dfs<'a>(maze: &crate::entities::Maze) -> Node<'static> {
    let mut traversed = Vec::new();
    let mut frontier = Vec::new();
    let mut seen: HashSet<crate::entities::Position> = HashSet::new();

    let parent = Node {
        parent: None,
        position: maze.start // position is just a holder for row and column
    };
    frontier.push(parent);

    loop {
        if frontier.is_empty() {
            panic!("No solution found!")
        }
        let current: Node<'static> = frontier.pop().expect("There must be a node here");
        let position = current.position;
        if current.position == maze.exit {
            break current;
        } else {
            if !seen.contains(&current.position) {
                let neighbours = maze.get_neighbours(current.position).iter().map(|pos| Node {
                    parent: Some(&current), // this line is not compiling
                    position: *pos
                }).collect::<Vec<Node>>();
                frontier.append(&mut neighbours); 
                traversed.push(current);
            }
        }
        seen.insert(position);
    }
}
```

But I am getting a compile error:

```
27 |                     parent: Some(&current),
   |                                   ^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Is using `Rc<_>` as a wrapper an option here?

Comment: Since you try to return a single `Node`, while all the nodes are created inside `dfs` you'll have to either use `Rc`, so the whole nodes structure lives for longer than the function call, or somehow return the whole owned path of your DFS (say as a `Vec<Position>`)

Comment: How do I use Rc, like this:

parent: Option<Rc<&'a Node<'a>>>,

Comment: @Manuelarte Rc owns its data so no need for a reference.

Comment: but then, when I do Rc::new(current) it complains that Node doesn't implement Copy trait

Comment: @Manuelarte You need to make sure not to use `current` after moving it into the `Rc`. You can even use `let current = Rc::new(current);` to shadow the old variable so it's impossible to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is you management of the nodes. Notice that a node is first created by the matrix, then put into the `frontier` and lastly moved into `traversed`. This means that you cannot use references to your nodes, since they might move, invalidating the reference.

The solution is to have a central store of node, and then using indices when referring to them. This of course, doesn't play nice with you implementation of `Node`, but you could change that to use indices instead of references to parents.

Comment: This works well for locals, but would need to be converted to be usefully returnable.